# Select all rows with max date for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query returning the data as shown below. But I need to exclude the rows with MODIFIEDDATETIME shown in red as they have a lower time stamp by COMMITRECID. As depicted in the data, there may be multiple rows with the max time stamp by COMMITRECID.

```
SELECT REQCOMMIT.COMMITSTATUS, NOTEHISTORY.NOTE, NOTEHISTORY.MODIFIEDDATETIME,   NOTEHISTORY.COMMITRECID
FROM REQCOMMIT INNER JOIN NOTEHISTORY ON REQCOMMIT.RECID = NOTEHISTORY.COMMITRECID 
WHERE REQCOMMIT.PORECID = 1234
```

Here is the result of the above query

[image: Query Result]

The desired result is only 8 rows with 5 in Green and 3 in Black (6 in Red should get eliminated).

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `RANK`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  R.COMMITSTATUS, 
            N.NOTE, 
            N.MODIFIEDDATETIME,   
            N.COMMITRECID,
            RN = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY N.COMMITRECID ORDER BY N.MODIFIEDDATETIME)
    FROM REQCOMMIT R
    INNER JOIN NOTEHISTORY N
        ON R.RECID = N.COMMITRECID 
    WHERE R.PORECID = 1234 
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

As an aside, please try to use tabla aliases instead of the whole table name in your queries.

*Disclaimer: You said that you wanted the max date, but the selected values in your post were those with the min date, so I used that criteria in my answer

Answer (score 1):

This method just limits your history table to those with the `MIN`date as you described.

```
SELECT 
    REQCOMMIT.COMMITSTATUS, 
    NOTEHISTORY.NOTE, 
    NOTEHISTORY.MODIFIEDDATETIME,   
    NOTEHISTORY.COMMITRECID
FROM REQCOMMIT 
INNER JOIN NOTEHISTORY ON REQCOMMIT.RECID = NOTEHISTORY.COMMITRECID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COMMITRECID, MIN(MODIFIEDDATETIME) DT FROM NOTEHISTORY GROUP BY COMMITRECID) a on a.COMMITRECID = NOTEHISTORY.COMMITRECID  and a.DT = NOTEHISTORY.MODIFIEDDATETIME
WHERE REQCOMMIT.PORECID = 1234
```